# How do I parse data returned from the Graph Api

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a PHP form (index.php) that uses the Facebook Graph API to create an event. A form is used to capture user input, and this data is POSTed back to the API to create the event.
This is the same code as explained in this tutorial: http://www.masteringapi.com/tutorials/how-to-create-facebook-events-using-graph-api/49/

The result of this is that, it returns the ID of the event that just got created.

```
    <?php

    $app_id = "APP_key";
    $app_secret = "APP_secret";
    $my_url = "URL";

    $code = $_REQUEST["code"];

    if(empty($code)) {
    $auth_url = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id="
    . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url)
    . "&scope=create_event";
    echo("<script>top.location.href='" . $auth_url . "'</script>");
    }

    $token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id="
    . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url)
    . "&client_secret=" . $app_secret
    . "&code=" . $code;
    $access_token = file_get_contents($token_url);

    $event_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me/events?" . $access_token;

    ?>

    <style>
    label {float: left; width: 100px;}
    input[type=text],textarea {width: 210px;}
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div id="inputForm"> 
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo $event_url; ?>" method="post">
    <p><label for="name">Event Name</label><input type="text" name="name" value="" /></p>
    <p><label for="description">Event Description</label><textarea name="description"></textarea></p>
    <p><label for="location">Location</label><input type="text" name="location" value="" /></p>
    <p><label for="">Start Time</label><input type="text" name="start_time" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); ?>" /></p>
    <p><label for="end_time">End Time</label><input type="text" name="end_time" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m")  , date("d")+1, date("Y"))); ?>" /></p>
    <p><label for="picture">Event Picture</label><input type="file" name="picture" /></p>
    <p>
        <label for="privacy_type">Privacy</label>
        <input type="radio" name="privacy_type" value="OPEN"   checked='checked'/>Open&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type="radio" name="privacy_type" value="CLOSED" />Closed&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type="radio" name="privacy_type" value="SECRET" />Secret&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
   </p>
   <p><input type="submit" value="Create Event" /></p>
   </form>
   </div>

   <?php
```

This code works great, but I'm trying to modify this code such that, index.php posts data to $event_url to create the event, but redirects you to a confirmation page that displays a message such as:

"Event successfully created! Click here to access your event", and clicking "here" would redirect you the event on Facebook.

Any thoughts on how this could be done?

Answer (score 0):

Change `$event_url` to a page like `event_submitter.php` on your site and add the `access_token` as a hidden field on your form.

The `event_submitter` page should take the `$_POST` data, strip out the `access_token` (You could eliminate this part if you used the php SDK), reformat the rest of the `$_POST` data, send this to to the Facebook API via cURL and examine the response.

If you get the correct response, you can then generate the output you want from that.

Comment: Thanks! I passed the $access_token variable as a hidden input. On "event_submitter.php", used cURL to POST back to Facebook: 
        $event_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me/events?" . $access_token;
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $event_url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "I-am-browser");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        var_dump(json_decode($response, true));

Comment: However, I see that it returns an empty "data[]" array. Is there something wrong with the way cURL has been used?

Comment: Are you sure you've structured your url correctly? You should have an `access_token=` in there? It also looks like you've got a `;` before you concatenate your `$access_token`. I don't see where you are telling cURL to submit this as a POST or including your POST data in your cURL call. If that's the case, you're making a GET call, and you'll get empty data if your profile doesn't currently have any events.

Comment: If you're new to cURL, this is a lot easier if you use the PHP SDK IMHO.